# Flask Docker - 2 Containers Communication - ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with url:

Tags: docker, flask, connection

So... I'm testing the communication between 2 flask apps in 2 containers. The idea is to have a WebApp to send a GET request to a DataService app and show me the result. I'm running both services from independent containers.

I'm getting an error: "ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool: Max retries exceeded with url" when I access my WebApp Route.

See below the relevant code:

App 1: Data Service

```
from flask import Flask, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/data")
def index():
    data = {"id": "testID", "value": "testValue"}
    return json.dumps(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

App2: Web Service

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/app')
def index():
    r = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0:5001/data')
    return r.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I dont use docker-compose, so I'm building the 2 containers independently.

App1 and App2 Dockerfile are exactly the same:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER me "my@email.com"
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

I run the containers and assign the WebService to port 5000 and DataService to port 5001.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 web
sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5000 data
```

If I go to my DataService route directly from my browser (http://0.0.0.0:5001/data) I get the expected result, but when I try to access it from the WebApp route (http://0.0.0.0:5000/app) I get the error below:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /data (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f20d55aeb90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

I tried using the container name in my request URL from the webapp service, but got the same error. Like this:

```
def index():
    r = requests.get('http://data_service_container_name:5001/data')
    return r.text
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't make request to 0.0.0.0. It means any IPv4 address at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you started your two containers (`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 ...`) will attach both containers to the default bridge network.

If you issue a `docker network inspect bridge` command, then you'll find the 2 containers under the containers section.

On the default bridge network containers can see each other by container IP. Which means that if you put the container IP into your request URL, then your request should go through. You can get the container IP of the data container if you `docker container inspect <container_name>` the running container.

A better option is to create your own user defined network. Just simply issue `docker network create mynetwork` and you will see a new network in `docker network ls`.

On a user defined network containers can see each other by container name (and IP). So this time if you start your containers with a command like `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --network mynetwork ...` then you can use the container name in the request URL.

You can even define the container name with a command like `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --network mynetwork --name data_container ...` for the data container.

In order to make this more Docker like, I'd suggest to use Compose. In this case you don't need to define the container name, because containers started by compose can access each other by service name. Compose will create a custom bridge network automatically, but you can also define your own.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. I tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting the same error.
I also tried creating 2 different networks and running each container on its own network. Still the same error. I'll try Docker Composer tomorrow and see if I get any luck there.
Cheers!

Comment: Attach the containers to the same network, so that they can see each other. If you share your current code and commands, maybe I can help further.

Comment: I first attached both containers to the same network, but still got the same error. My files are still exactly as described above. I'm initiating them using this:
`sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name web_container --network test_network web_app` 
and
`sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5000 --name data_container --network test_network data_app`

Comment: Sorry, I did edit the request url to: `http://data_container:5001/data`

Comment: Ok... I tried docker-compose and I'm still getting the same error. See below my composer file:
`version: '3'

services:
    web:
      restart: always
      build: ./web_directory
      container_name: web_container
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"

    data:
      build: ./data_directory
      container_name: data_container
      ports:
        - "5001:5000"`
This is frustrating... It isnt supposed to be this complicated. This is pretty much the simplest example of 2 containers talking to each other. I must be doing something very wrong...

Comment: in case of Compose the name of the service is to be used in your request url as host, i.e. `data`. Please try to `docker exec -ti <container_name> /bin/bash` and see if  you can ping the containers from one another by container name or service name or IP. This usually helps to see find the root cause of such issues.

Comment: I was able to ping the containers from each other, but I still have the same error. I'm close to giving up on this one... Maybe I'll try pottery instead :)

Comment: :) Pinging is a good sign. Try to curl the endpoint from the other container. Maybe the connection wotks now and the bug is somewhere else.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for all the help so far. Problem is not solved, but I'm actually learning how to debug these things. So... when I try to curl the data endpoint from the web_service I get: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 5001: Connection refused`. Do you think it could be related to firewall or maybe the host address of 0.0.0.0 in both services?

Comment: I conquered the beast. Finally made it work. I re-did everything from scratch and it worked fine in the end... I think I had the wrong service name in my URL. Thanks again for your help bruh!

Comment: Glad it's working. If you wanna learn more about Docker before trying pottery, just download a complementary copy of the Docker book I wrote. Use the coupon code RODRIGOB on https://takacsmark.com/get-started-with-docker-in-your-projects-through-examples/ and enjoy :)